# Where can I get a website/web application template with user authentication functionality already built in?

Tags: templates, web-applications, authentication

I want to start work on a new web application, but I really don't want to re-invent the wheel. I want to make a simple web application that provides some basic functionality, and looks really good. Does anybody know of anything (even if it isn't free) where I could get something that has a good framework laid down already? Where I can have a login/sign up function already built in and ready for use? I have seen a few ecommerce sites that fit the build, but Id have to do a ton of clean-up. I was hoping to find something that was basic, and ready for adding to right away.

I would think that word press or drupal would have something, but I've been looking and haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out Thin PHP Framework, it has OAuth built in allow you to login with popular services Google, Twitter, Facebook... or you can use its simple username, password login. Check out the demo here:

http://demo.thinphp.com

website:

http://thinphp.com

Answer (score 0):

Choose your language, there are a lot of different, good frameworks, but you will do best with the language you already know. Wordpress, Drupal, Django, Plone, Joomla, Typo3 are great, and of course they have user authentication.

Looking good is something different, that's design and it is done in CSS. And every CMS or web framework usually has good default CSS templates as a starting point.